# Incompatible types in argument

Tags: java, bean-validation, checker-framework

When I compile my code with [The Checker Framwork](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/) it complains:

```
incompatible types in argument.
  found   : null
  required: @NonNull String
```

for the first argument of:

```
ResultSet rs = connection.getMetaData().getColumns(null, schemaName, tableName, null)
```

I know that [DatabaseMetadata.getColumns()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) allows a null catalog (the first argument). How do I tell the Checker Framework as much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gili answered, you can use [stub-files](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#stub) but, if you find a missing/incorrect annotation in the JDK, please report it to the Checker Framework mailing list [checker-framework-discuss@googlegroups.com](http://mailTo:checker-framework-discuss@googlegroups.com)  or report it as an issue in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/checker-framework/issues/list).

With each release, an [Annotated JDK](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#skeleton-using) is bundled with the Checker Framework.  It is used solely to retrieve annotations for common methods in the JDK.  It is used automatically when you use the Checker Framework.

This annotation has been included since of Checker Framework release 1.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that framework; does it respect @SuppressWarnings in the context you're interested in?

https://checkerframework.org/manual/#suppressing-warnings-nullness

Comment: Yes, but I wanted a more fine-grained solution (and also I wanted to avoid having to @SuppressWarnings multiple times for the same problem across multiple files. I ended up finding out about [stub files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18809315/14731) and they seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

In section [Annotating Libraries](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#annotating-libraries) the authors write you can either provide [stub-files](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#stub) or rewrite the class files in question.

I ended up using stub files as they seemed easier to get started with.